# How does the zero functor fail to be exact/additive?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Just learning some homological algebra, in particular the fact that an additive, exact functor between abelian categories will preserve homology.

A question is in my head whose answer I'm sure is obvious: isn't the constant functor at zero additive and exact? And yet it does not preserve any non-trivial homology...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does. If $C$ is any chain complex in your additive category and $F = 0$ the zero functor, then $H_n(FC) \cong F\bigl(H_n(C)\bigr)$ for each $n \in \mathbf Z$, as both sides are zero.

Comment: Oh, of course. I was mistaking what it meant to "preserve homology". Thanks.